# How to reverse a txt file in python 3.8?

Tags: python, file, txt

```
data = data2 = data3 = ""

with open('pushkin.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as fp:
    data = fp.read()

with open('romeo.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as fp:
    data2 = fp.read()
with open('byron.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as fp:
    data3 = fp.read()


data += "\n"
data += data2 + data3

with open('poems.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    fp.write(data)
```

With this code, I have transferred three text files into one.
Now I need to turn over text in that file, like this:

```
ABC       CDA
BCA  -->  BCA
CDA       ABC
```

but I don't know how. I thought using `reverse()` or `reversed()`, but that makes it just from
`abc` to `cba`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To be clear: you want the **lines of** the file to be reversed? Did you try using a reading method that would separate the lines of the file first? Did you try reading the documentation to look for something like that? Does that solve the problem for you?

Comment: I really tried looking for it, but no, it didn't help me.

Comment: How do the ABC etc relate to the content. Is each a separate file, so that you want to reverse the sequence of concatenation? Is each a word or a line and logically unrelated to its source file? How would you describe in words the desired algorithm?

Comment: "I really tried looking for it, but no, it didn't help me." What happens if you try putting `python read lines of a file` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+read+lines+of+a+file)?

Comment: Note that even if you got an answer, please [edit] the question to make it clear what the requirements are. Otherwise, the question is not useful for future readers that need to figure out if their task matches yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reverse()` to reverse the order of elements in a list after saving all the contents as `list` type to `data` variable, not the specific string, as follows:

```py
data = []

with open('1.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as fp: # ABC
    data += fp.readlines()
    # data -> ['ABC\n']

with open('2.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as fp: # BCA
    data += fp.readlines()
    # data -> ['ABC\n', 'BCA\n']

with open('3.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as fp: # CDA
    data += fp.readlines()
    # data -> ['ABC\n', 'BCA\n', 'CDA\n']

data.reverse() # data becomes ['CDA\n', 'BCA\n', 'ABC\n']

with open('result.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    fp.write("".join(data))
```

```
# result.txt
CDA
BCA
ABC
```

Comment: Hello Park! This code worked for me, big thanks to you, gonna accept the answer in 4 minutes.

Comment: Heads up that this reverses the order of the lines, not (just) the order of the files. If each file contains more than a single line, this may or may not be desired.

Comment: @Clownpiece Pleased to help you. Just be cautiuous when you use `reverse()` for `list` and `str` ;)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Oh, you're right. I corrected the point. Thx